# What is the solution to digitally sign email apart from S/MIME and GPG/OpenPGP

Tags: encryption, digital-signature, pgp, gnupg, smime

I have tried to implement S/MIME, however, I've found out that S/MIME seems to be obsolete, in my perspective. Since S/MIME cannot operate on Google Chrome or Edge.

Another solution I found is Gpg4win but it also doesn't work with Outlook 365.

Is there any other solution I could implement so that I could sign email from both Outlook client and Outlook 365?

Those tools such as AdobeSign, DocuSign, SigningHub works only for signing documents but not sign email.

Comment: gmail supports s/mime.  https://www.paubox.com/blog/gmail-encryption-settings s/mime works at the email header level, so it's supported at the client level, and a browser isn't an email client.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion but my company only use Exchange online :(

Comment: [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/securitycompliance/email-encryption#what-encryption-options-are-available-for-my-office-365-subscription) suggests that S/MIME should be possible with Office 365.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich The things is I have to use only Internet Explorer which no one in my company is using IE now.

Comment: *"The things is I have to use only Internet Explorer which no one in my company is using IE now. "* - this comment does not make much sense for me since in your question you explicitly mention Chrome and Edge as the relevant browsers for you. Anyway, S/MIME is officially support for Office 365 and Exchange so I'm not sure what alternatives you expect and why. Also, S/MIME is not considered obsolete.

Comment: Also, office365 supports imap, and Thunderbird (as well as other) email clients support s/mime.  s/mime is far from obsolte.   https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/pop3-and-imap4/pop3-and-imap4

Comment: GPG4O should work in Outlook ánd O365.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I'm guessing that by "_The things is I have to use only Internet Explorer_" the OP means that solution only works (or, at least, they think it only works) when using IE... since most of the OPs users _don't_ use IE (they use Chrome/Edge), then this is a problem.

Comment: GPG4O is quite expensive for 750 people. Sadly.